# How to run file with afk script on another text file

Tags: linux, awk

I try to use awk in file(awk.007) on a file.txt
If some string begins with a letter "j" print.

In awk file  I have this:

```
^J* {print $0}



 Name Surname
   Maths 2 5 6
```

I run it by cat file.txt | awk -f awk.007 but each time it show:
Syntax error: ^
If I run awk by command line everything workning fine.

Comment: Escape `]` by using `awk '/^\]/' file.txt`

Comment: DIsregarding everything else as  incomprehensible, except: _If some string begins with a letter "j" print._: `awk '/^j/' file`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regular expression needs to be in `//`'s:

```
awk '/^J/' file.txt
```

`^J*` will match every line, btw, since `*` is **0** or more repetitions. And the default action for a pattern is `print $0`, so you don't really need to include that.